# Dataflow // High System Lag and Slow Watermark

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am in the process of testing a data pipeline that is a hybrid between a streaming pipeline with messages that point to GCS data files. The goal of the system is to allow for a pub sub message to dictate the parameters of the deduplicating, groups, and file format (csv, tsv, pipe delimited, etc...). I have the system running successfully for smaller data sets, but seems to be struggling with larger dataset.

The reason why we have such a setup is that a majority of that datasets can be grouped together. Such as a company selling multiple products that potentially can come in messages, we would want to group these products together. We leverage side inputs on these elements to allow for processing.

The data needs to be accurate, so adding discard to late data to a trigger is not allowed. All data currently has the watermark of the PubSub message which is anticipated.

**Is there something I am missing in the implementation or is my expectation of performance too high?**

For example:

```
        message = (p 
            | 'Read from Pub/Sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=self._subscription).with_output_types(bytes)
            | 'Convert to JSON' >> beam.Map(lambda message_json: json.loads(message_json))
            | 'Add timestamp to message' >> beam.Map(apply_datetime, key='__message_dt')
            | 'timestamps' >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestampDoFn())
            | 'Window into Fixed Intervals' >> beam.WindowInto(
                windowfn=FixedWindows(600)  # 10 minutes,
            ) 

        unique_record_keys = message | "Unique Keys" >> beam.Map(
            lambda m: m.get('unique_record_keys'),
        )  # Fetch the list of attributes/key that we can use for first round of deduplication

        record_grouping_keys = message | "Record Grouping Keys" >> beam.Map(
            lambda m: m.get('record_grouping_keys')
        )  # Fetch list of keys for group elements together as they will be stored as an object with multiple entities in a list.

        data = message | 'Read all files' >> ReadAllFromDelimitedSource(file_location_key='file_locations')  # Custom PTransform that essentially is beam.io.filebasedsource.FileBasedSource pointing to a GCS file. This file is a denormalized file and we are trying to normalize it

        key_data = data | "Keyify on Unique" >> beam.ParDo(
            GenerateKey(),
            keys_list=beam.pvalue.AsList(unique_record_keys)
        )  # Generate a key for hashing to remove duplicates rows based on columns of the source files from GCS

        grouped_data = key_data | 'Group Per Unique Key' >> beam.GroupByKey()  # Hangs up here on large dataset for hours on end with watermark not passing through window and data left unprocessed
```

Smaller dataset that processes successfully:
[image: Slow, but successful processing of window]

Larger dataset that hangs (also note that it looks like it fires a handful of times to this step. Original dataset is only 2 million lines from the GCS file, this is definitely adding to the issue):

[image: Data that hangs]

I have bumped the memory and CPU as it looks like it was hanging on that, but to no avail. It experienced the same issue later on.

---

Update: 2022-06-05

On further inspection, the code was operating correctly. After increasing memory and performing a full inspections on the datasets, the groups were missing on a certain column. On correction, data processed as expectedly in 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double check the grouping key and ensure that you are not attempting to group on too large of a dataset that will only take time to finish.

The issue experienced on this problem was that the group-by key set had an error and was not properly grouping on the unique elements and therefore all keys were considered repeated therefore the whole window'd dataset was considered a unique set. This did not show on the smaller datasets and only existing on the data-driven nature of the messages.

Upon correction of the group-by keys, double check your casing, at the key set, i.e. `Keyify on Unique`, the system was able to correctly group into smaller datasets and properly define unique sets.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal of the system is to allow for a pub sub message to dictate the parameters of the bounded dataset and its processing terms

I'm not sure what it means to an application depending on the system or how it would work (maybe depending on how you consume the side input unique_record_keys in your GenerateKey DoFn). From the look of the pipeline, you are applying panes of arbitrary pub/sub messages with artificial timestamps to all bounded data again and again. What does the key_data hold and what does the GBK mean if all your keys are unique?

Performance wise, you can try [Dataflow shuffle](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shuffle) if it's not enabled.

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn’t need that since the PubSub sink applies the time stamp already? (My assumption as well, but had issues with it running.) We had trouble with operations after not working without it.

The `key_data` is a hash key based on attributes of the dictionary values to allow for deduplication on certain attributes. We could have multiple sources provide the same data and we want to only have one of the sources provide the authority.  

I do not believe we can use dataflow shuffle as this is a steaming pipeline and it specifies batch.

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Pub/Sub has at-least-once delivery and Dataflow has exactly-once execution. Normally, you shouldn't need to do deduplications. I think the thing I'm not sure about is your `data` is a bounded PCollection read from a file while the side input `unique_record_keys` is an unbounded PCollection from a Pub/Sub source. When you join them, since the unbounded PCollection are keyed by both their original key and the arbitrary window/pane you emit (the 10-minute window), I'm not sure how the window information works with the bounded `data`. Maybe that's why you assign timestamps to make it work?

Comment: So the window information you introduced will affect the GBK because keys are (real key, window). And your `grouped_data` will be grouped into (real key, window) pairs. Unless you have control of which real key must fall within a single window by controlling your Pub/Sub topic, a piece of your data might end up falling into multiple groups. Based on your own answer, I guess you have already achieved what you wanted. If possible, please also share what error you had in the group-by key set so that others can learn from it. Thanks!

Comment: I would think it works because it is transforming the unbounded and yielding rules of the message and therefore it is all classified as unbounded still; the side inputs have the same window. 
GBK is based on the prior `keyify` which is a concat of the dictionary keys and a single window can yield 70K different keys. The issue experienced was the window was issuing only a single key and the machine was hanging on processing 2 million keys for the GBK. No error was emitted, but no watermark either. The system would hang indefinitely and backup all behind it.